# I want to create multi admin store in opencart where each admin should get some specific data not admin data.

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

Actually I am created one user group and created different admin but my problem is I am getting all data whatever inside admin. i Want to get only specific data for a particular admin. Is it possible through tool in **OPENCART**. If any one did kindly explain me.

Answer (score 0):

The User section lets you customize which users can access the admin side of the store, and what sections can be accessed or modified by them.

1. Before you begin creating user profiles, you should visit **System > Users > User Groups** to set specific access and modification permissions.
2. With the user groups set up, the **individual users** can be saved to the administration side of your store under **System  >Users > Users**.
3. The User Group selected from the drop down box will assign specific permissions to the user.

Check links,
[create user](http://docs.opencart.com/system/users/user/),
[create user group](http://docs.opencart.com/system/users/groups/)

Comment: Already I did this process, but my problem is I am getting all data whatever in our admin back-end.

Comment: What do you mean by Specific data?

Comment: Actually I want to create sales_manager dashboard same like admin dashboard where all details like total customer under that specific sales_manager and so on.  I am already created a dashboard based users_Group, but the problem is  I am getting all data on dashboard whatever coming on admin dashboard. I want to get only data for that particular sales_manager.